# Возникает очень много ошибок Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined at HTMLDocument.document.onscroll

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, type-error

Вот js для смены класса про скролле.

```
<script>
document.onscroll = function (event) {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop);
    if(scrollTop > 300) {
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-mp')[0];

        el.className = 'menu-mp2';

    }
    else if(scrollTop < 300) {
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-mp2')[0];

        el.className = 'menu-mp';

    }

}
```

Но при прокрутке возникает бесконечное количество ошибок. Ругается на строчку

el.className = 'menu-mp2'

и на строчку

el.className = 'menu-mp';

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что `document.getElementsByClassName('menu-mp')` возращает пустой массив. То есть не найден элемент с классом `menu-mp`. Далее вы из пустого массива берёте первый элемент и получаете `undefined`, вместо `HTMLElement`. Потом пытаетесь в `undefined` в свойство `className` что-то присвоить. В итоге возникает эта ошибка.

Comment: Отличный ответ! А можете еще посоветовать, как от ошибки избавиться?

Comment: Но как получается, что элемент не найден, если скрипт выполняется?

Comment: А что должно мешать скрипту выполняться? Сделайте так, что бы функция `getElementsByClassName` возвращала хотя бы один элемент. Что для этого нужно, я, разумеется, не знаю. Может быть у вас css-селектор неправильно написан. Может элемент отсутствует на странице. Разбирайтесь

Answer (score 0):

В итоге работает без проблем вот такой код. Надеюсь кому-то пригодится!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
//caches a jQuery object containing the header element
var header = $(".menu-mp");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 300) {
        header.removeClass('menu-mp').addClass("menu-mp2");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("menu-mp2").addClass('menu-mp');
    }
});
});
```